# Concrete5.7.5.2 - How to get Topics tree attributes values into a select box?

Tags: drop-down-menu, tree, attributes, concrete5-5.7

I have a Topics tree which I use as an attribute on a page:

Categories-
-Topic 1
-Topic 2
-Topic 3

How can I get the topics into an array in a block? Which I can then use in a select box? e.g.

```
$topics = ("Topic 1", "Topic 2", "Topic 3);
echo $form->select('categories', $topics);
```

And if my select box is on the right most side of the page, it always has the right border missing. If I move it anywhere else, it shows fine. Anyone else have this?

BTW, for those who want to get values from a select box attribute:

```
use Concrete\Core\Attribute\Key\CollectionKey as CollectionKey;
use Concrete\Attribute\Select\Controller as SelectController;
use Concrete\Core\Attribute\Type as AttributeType;

$ak = CollectionKey::getByHandle('region');
$at = AttributeType::getByHandle('select');
$satc = new SelectController($at);
$satc->setAttributeKey($ak);   
$values = $satc->getOptions()->getOptions();
foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
    $this->options[$value->getSelectAttributeOptionID()] = $value->getSelectAttributeOptionValue();
}
```

Thank you.

[SOLVED]
Thanks to Mike, here's a piece of working code:

```
use Concrete\Core\Tree\Type\Topic as TopicTree;  
public $category = array('');

public function view() {
...
    $this->requireAsset('core/topics');  
    $tt = new TopicTree();  
    $tree = $tt->getByName('My Categories');  
    $node = $tree->getRootTreeNodeObject();  
    $node->populateChildren();  
    if (is_object($node)) {  
        foreach($node->getChildNodes() as $key => $category) {  
            if ($category instanceof \Concrete\Core\Tree\Node\Type\Topic) {  
                $this->category[$category->getTreeNodeDisplayName()] = $category->getTreeNodeDisplayName();  
            }  
        }  
    }  
...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this within your block controller...

```
private function getTopics($topicTreeName)
{
    $this->requireAsset('core/topics');
    $tt = new TopicTree();
    /** @var Topic $tree */
    $tree = $tt->getByName($topicTreeName);
    /** @var TopicCategory $node */
    $node = $tree->getRootTreeNodeObject();
    $node->populateChildren();
    $topics = [];

    /** @var Concrete/Core/Tree/Node/Type/Topic $topic */
    foreach ($node->getChildNodes() as $topic) {
        if ($topic instanceof \Concrete\Core\Tree\Node\Type\Topic) {
            $topics[] = [
              'id'   => $topic->getTreeNodeID(),
              'name' => $topic->getTreeNodeDisplayName(),
            ];
        }
    }

    return $topics;
}
```

This will get you an array of topics and their Id's (I suspect you would want the id for the value of the select option) like this...

```
[[name=>'Topic 1', id => 1], [name=>'Topic 2', id => 2]..etc.]
```

...and then within your view function you can set the variable to make it available within the view template...

```
public function view() {
  $topics = $this->getTopics('My topic name');
  $this->set('topics', $topics);
}
```

You could just then iterate over the topics within your template to output the select list.

Hope that helps with how to get the list of topics?

Comment: Mike, Thanks a lot!!! It worked. Really appreciate it. I've updated my question with working code.